# How to apply a function on pandas dataframe columns in parallel?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing, feature-engineering

I have a pandas dataframe of `1million X 1000` dimension.
Columns are categorical variables. I want to encode them.

I already got encodeing model from sklearn and fitted it. Now want to transform the columns of my dataframe in parallel.

```
transformed_X = encoding_model.transform(X)
```

in the above X is my dataframe to be encoded.Here it does in serial manner.
Is there a way to apply the transform function in parallel to each column of my dataframe X?

Comment: Need more details. What does the `encoding_model` do? Does it change the values in or create new columns for single column? Can you show an example?

Comment: i am using library "category_encoders" python library to encode my categorical variables. Since my dataframe is very large, its very slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to 1 hot encode your categorical variables you can use [pd.get_dummies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) function

`df = pd.get_dummies(df)`